# Load image from photo library into my UIImageView but image does not change when I restart the app

Tags: ios, swift

I have imageView and a button to upload image from photo library and keep it in the imageView i do documentDirectory so when I upload a photo to the imageView it save the image in the imageView even if I close the application.

But my problem is whenever I upload new photo it change without any problem. But when I close the app and start it again the old photo returns.

```
func saveImage(image : UIImage, imageName: String){
    let documentDirectoryPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    let fileURL = documentDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
    if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0),
        !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            print("Image saved")
        } catch {
            print("Image save error:", error)
        }
    }
}

func getImage(imageName: String) -> UIImage?{
    let documentDirectoryPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileURL = documentDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path)
    return image
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    imageView.image = image
    saveImage(image:image!, imageName: "profile.jpg")
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let image = getImage(imageName: "profile.jpg"){
        imageView.image = image}
    }
```

I was expecting the image change and will be save even when I close app.

But actually it always return to the first image I upload.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in `saveImage`, you are checking that the file exists already, and not doing the save if it does exist. That would mean that the first time you selected an image, it will save properly, but any further image picks will update the control, but not the file, which would cause the old image to appear again the next time you open the app. So you probably want to remove that `fileExists` check from your if altogether.

You can verify that is what's happening by adding an `else` to that `if` statement in `saveImage` that does a `print()`, and that should end up in your log file the second time you select an image:

```
if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0),
    !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
    // ...
}
else {
    print("File exists -- image not saved")
}
```

Comment: Sure thing! Added to the original answer.

Comment: still same result when close and open the app shows the old image

Comment: Did you look in the log to see if that message appeared? If it did, then you know it's the fileExists check is the problem, and that removing it is the solution.

Comment: [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

Comment: now its saying File exists -- image not saved even for the new picture and the old one dosent change

Comment: Okay, that verifies that the `FileManager.default.fileExists` condition is the problem. Remove that and give it a try.